# Wget not downloading the url given to him

Tags: shell, wget

My wget request is

```
wget --reject jpg,png,css,js,svg,gif --convert-links -e robots=off --content-disposition --timestamping --recursive --domains appbase.io --no-parent --output-file=logfile --limit-rate=200k -w 3 --random-wait docs.appbase.io
```

On the docs.appbase.io page, there are two different type of a href

```
<a href="v2.0/concepts/datamodel.html">v2.0</a>
<a href="http://docs.appbase.io/v3.0/changelog/changelog.html">v3.0</a>
```

The first link (v2.0) is recursively download but not the v3.0

What should I do to recursively download the full URL as well?

Comment: The command is fine, I think you've got the wait set too high... try lowering it. Also, the second url you've given is invalid - 404 not found.

Comment: It worked, thanks. It was the mistake from my side :)